# Processing: Write HTML file from arduino input

Tags: java, html, arduino, processing

I'm trying to make a plant monitor using an Arduino and processing.
Processing writes an html file based on the sensor input by the Arduino.
WinSCP is monitoring the file created for changes and directly uploads trough FTP when the file has changed.

The Arduino is sending the following to processing via serial:

```
45
0
31
40
x
```

Using the following code in processing I write an html page with this data:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
String dataReading = "";
int lol = 0;
String string0 = "<h1>Jurze Plants <img src=\"https://html-online.com/editor/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-laughing.gif\" alt=\"laughing\" /></h1>";
String string1 = "Moisture Level: ";
String string2 = " %<br> Motorstate: ";
String string3 = "<br> Temperature: ";
String string4 = " &deg;C<br> Humidity: ";
String string5 = "%<br>";

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);

    myPort = new Serial(this, "COM4", 9600); 
    myPort.bufferUntil('x');
}

void draw() {
}

String [] dataOutput = {};

void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
    dataReading = myPort.readString();
    if (dataReading!=null) {
        dataOutput = split(dataReading, '\n');
        String [] tempfile  = {string0,string1,dataOutput[1],string2,dataOutput[2],string3,dataOutput[3],string4,dataOutput[4],string5  };
        println("saving to html file...");
        saveStrings("data/index.html",tempfile);
    }
}
```

The html code I get the first time is :

```
<h1>Jurze Plants <img src="https://html-online.com/editor/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-laughing.gif" alt="laughing" /></h1>
Moisture Level: 46   %<br>
Motorstate: 0  <br> 
Temperature:31.00 &deg;C <br> 
Humidity: 35.00%  <br>
```

Though, after it gets the data from the Arduino for the second time it looks like this:

```
<h1>Jurze Plants <img src="https://html-online.com/editor/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-laughing.gif" alt="laughing" /></h1>
Moisture Level:      %<br>
Motorstate: 46  <br> 
Temperature:0 &deg;C <br> 
Humidity: 31.00%  <br>
```

I guess there is something wrong with the array?
Any help would be highly appreciated! :D

Comment: [espruino](http://www.espruino.com/) for the win!!!

Comment: could you show your `split` function ?

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire     `dataOutput = split(dataReading, '\n');`

Comment: @JérômeTeisseire Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question. The `split()` function is built into Processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to debug your code! (We can't really do this for you, since we don't have your Arduino.)

**Step 1:** In your `serialEvent()` function, use the `println()` function to print out the value of `dataReading`. Is the value what you expect?

**Step 2:** Print out the value of `dataOutput`. Is that what you expect? Print out each index. Are they all what you expect? Check for extra spaces and control characters.

**Step 3:** Are the indexes what you expect them to be? I see you're starting with index `1` instead of index `0`. Is that what you meant to do?

The point is, you have to print out the values of every variable to make sure they're what you expect. When you find the variable with the wrong value, you can trace back through your code to figure out exactly what's happening.

Comment: `dataReading` gives the correct output, `dataOutput`gives 1 space the first time and 2 spaces the second time. must be something wrong with `dataOutput = split(dataReading, '\n');`

Comment: @Jurze Exactly. The `split()` function splits on every space, so if you have an extra space, then one of your indexes will be an empty "" String. You're going to have to either skip this index or strip the extra space out of the String before you split it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I fixed it now. in the last print of the loop of my Arduino I used `println()`instead of `print()`. That causes an extra space starting after the first loop :)